# BigQuery: some combination of using functions eats a lot of the compute while querying

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table like below

```
timestamp, user_id

1623250800, 1
1623250800, 2
1623250800, 3
1623250800, 1
1623250800, 2
.
.
.
over 200 million rows
```

AND I wanted to convert timestamp to date format like '2021-07-20' then count user_id

```
SELECT DATE(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp), 'Asia/Seoul')) AS dt,
    COUNT(user_id) cnt
FROM `project_id.dataset.table_name`
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = '2021-07-20'
GROUP BY dt
```

However, When I execute the query above, Its execution details on Google Console web UI shows that it eats a lot of compute resource for `DATE(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp), 'Asia/Seoul'))`

so that Max compute is over 3000 ms and Avg Compute is 273 ms with more than 200 million rows

Is there a better way or approach to reduce the compute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas come quick to mind:

1. Have you tried using _PARTITIONDATE instead of _PARTITIONTIME? Since you're imputing a date, is not worth the effort to transform to date the _PARTITIONTIME pseudocolumn.
2. You can use DATE(timestamp, timezone) directly, no need to use DATE(DATETIME()).

Therefore, query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp), 'Asia/Seoul') AS dt,
  COUNT(user_id) cnt
FROM 
  `project_id.dataset.table_name`
WHERE 
  _PARTITIONDATE = '2021-07-20'
GROUP BY 
  1
```

Comment: WOW! the way you suggested improved the execution time from 2.8 seconds to 1.6 seconds and max compute resource reduced from 3000 ms to 2000 ms!! Thanks!